# XPATH: Difference between preceding:: and ancestor::?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

What's the difference between `preceding::` and `ancestor::` in XPath 2.0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `preceding::` axis contains all the nodes in the document that come *before* this node, excluding this node's ancestors, which are in the `ancestor::` axis. For example, in this document:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c/>
  </b>
  <d>
    <e/>
  </d>
</a>
```

The "preceding" nodes of `e` would be `b` and `c`, but not `a` and `d` as they are `e`'s ancestors. Make sense?

([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#axes))